# Show iPhone notifications when new questions arrive in a subscribed filter

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, tag-filters

Currently I can choose to receive email updates about new questions that match filter criteria.

Add an option to show these updates as notifications in the iOS app.

**UPDATE:**

This is not a direct duplicate of [Receiving notifications for new questions with specific tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250068/receiving-notifications-for-new-questions-with-specific-tag). Filters allow to create complex rules that are sets of tag-site pairs like [hadoop-streaming](/questions/tagged/hadoop-streaming) on `Stack Overflow` + [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop) on `Super User` + [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop) on `Server Fault`.

At the moment, it is possible to receive email notifications from filters; it seems logical to extend it with mobile notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving notifications for new questions with specific tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250068/receiving-notifications-for-new-questions-with-specific-tag)