# Receiving notifications for new questions with specific tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, ios-app

I have been using the **Stack Exchange App (iOS)** for a little while now and have come to really appreciate what it brings to the table. But I have found one useful feature that does not seem to be implemented into application: the ability to receive notifications for a specific tag.

I feel this could be extremely useful in so many ways. The main reason I would like this feature is to follow certain tags that tend to be not widely used, for example the tag `diablo-3` on **Arqade**.

Questions are not all that common for this tag and although most do get answered fairly quickly I would like to know when a new question has been asked for this tag to give some input of my own. Instead I find the question days after when any more information seems not all that relevant anymore. Even if I have nothing to offer for the question I would know that the questions has been asked and could return later to take a look at the answers and learn something new.

I understand that certain sites (**SO**) could cause a few problems for users with spam of questions on certain tags but that would be the users choice by turning on these notifications.

The main question is: Does this feature already exist within the application and I have just overlooked it?

If not is this a feature that could be useful to other users of the application and all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this doesn't exist, and I would love it to! Most of my SO activity is following specific tags.

Comment: It's not within the application, but you can set up an email digest. http://i.stack.imgur.com/blZQq.png

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - That can only be a daily thing though, right? Not instant push notifications?

Comment: @chris, It's not instant push but I think you get the option of changing the frequency.

Comment: @Chris. As far as I know the email digest can be as frequent as 15 minutes.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I would also love to get a notification if a new question gets asked in a subscribed tag of mine

Comment: @HakanBaba - Great - thanks!